# How to extract columns about current commit in git local and remote repos

Tags: bash, git

A local `git` repository has checked out code from a remote `git` repository.  I am able to identify the current branch of the local `git` repository by typing in the following command on the local server:

```
git branch -vv
    * Issue_Example c167ce9 [origin/Issue_Example] who is here right now?  
      master        cf60eb7 [origin/master] Initial Commit
```

As you can see from the results above, the current branch is indicated using an `*` symbol.  Also, each line in the results contains the following columns (I have placed the values for the current branch alongside each column below to make it blindingly clear):

```
local branch = "Issue_Example"  
commit hash = c167ce9  
remote branch linked to local branch:  "origin/Issue_Example"  
description of commit:  "who is here right now?  "
```

How can I filter the results of the `git branch -vv` command to return only each column individually?  For example:

---

**First desired command:**

---

Get local branch name of current branch:

```
git branch -vv --current-branch-only --local-name-only
```

Would print out "Issue_Example"

---

**Second desired command:**

---

Get commit hash for the current branch:

```
git branch -vv --current-branch-only --commit-hash-only
```

Would print out "c167ce9"

---

**Third desired command:**

---

Get name of remote branch linked to current branch:

```
git branch -vv --current-branch-only --name-of-remote-branch-linked-to-local-branch-only
```

Would print out "origin/Issue_Example"

---

**Fourth desired command:**

---

Get description of commit:

```
git branch -vv --current-branch-only --description-of-commit-only
```

Would print out "who is here right now?"

---

---

**What actual syntax would be required to retrieve the information specified above?**  This is on a CentOS server, so we are using bash scripting if scripting is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Name of current branch

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

#### Hash of currently checked out commit (branch)

```
git rev-parse HEAD          # full hash
git rev-parse --short HEAD  # short hash
```

#### Remote tracking branch (upstream) of current branch

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{upstream}
```

#### Commit message subject of currently checked out commit

```
git log -1 --format="%s"
```

---

More info at [man git-rev-parse](https://gitirc.eu/git-rev-parse.html), [man git-log](https://gitirc.eu/git-log.html).